# How do I print the total number of iterations of the inner loop that were completed at the end of the program?

Tags: python

This is what I'm assigned to do:
[image]
I don't understand how to do the second half (Perfect number) of the rubric.

This is what I have so far:

```
def sumMultiple(num):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, num//2+1):
        if (num % i == 0):
            sum += i
    return sum

for in in range(1, 100000):
    if(sumMultiple(i) == i):
       print(i)
```

Comment: Please add your images/code.

Comment: I don’t see any images...

Comment: Providing code as text would be more useful than an image.

Comment: The inner loop is the one in your function, you could use a global variable to keep track of the number of iterations that its done, or refactor your code so it that function is just inline in the other loop.

Comment: Please copy-paste your description and code as *text* (and format it using the code block option): images are harder to search, and code can't be easily copy-paste for testing from an image.

Comment: Where does the "second half" start for you? Which part exactly do you not understand?

Comment: When you ask a question, it is best to add the code as code using the formatting provided. I edited your image code to proper formatting but ensure you properly add images and code when appropriate. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable that you iterate in the inner loop.

```
iterationCount = 0

def sumMultiple(num):
    global iterationCount
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, num//2+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            sum += i
            iterationCount++
    return sum

for i in range(1, 1000):
    if sumMultiple(i) == i:
        print(i)
print("Total iterations ", iterationCount)
```

Comment: very nice only 49.9 mil less iterations than mine!